How to create a shadow on one side of the div element?
I am trying to create a shadow only on one side like in the image below from Laravel.

or this

I tried using css pseudo-class for making the similar shadow. (see the code below) but the shadow isn't displayed only text are displayed.
#shadow {
  padding: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#shadow::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 4.625em;
  background: linear-gradient(360deg, rgba(99, 154, 220, 0.2) 70%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2), rgba(162, 209, 137, .2));
  filter: blur(10em);
  z-index: -1;
  width: calc(100% - 30%);
  margin-right: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

<section id="shadow">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <p>
          The Quick Brown Fox jumps over the lazy Dog
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>


Take a look in your browser devtools inspect facility to see where (if anywhere) your after pseudo element (not pseudo class) is and what dimensions it has. There are a few problems e.g. the pseudo element has no height, it's not positioned relative to its host element (did you want it to be?).
